# Не создаётся инстанс абстрактного класса с реализацией всех ф-кций

Tags: c++

Почему я не могу создать инстанс абстрактного класса с реализацией всех ф-кций ?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  virtual void f1() = 0;
  virtual void f2() = 0;
};
void A::f1()
{

}
void A::f2()
{

}

class B : public A
{
  void f1() override
  {

  }
};

class C : public A
{
  void f2() override
  {

  }
};

int main()
{
  C c;
}
```

Comment: By definition of abstract class. А вообще-то тут общаются по-русски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны либо определить метод f1 (и тогда он не должен быть равен 0 и класс не будет абстрактным), либо определить его в классе-наследнике A. Собственно, абстрактные классы и предназначены для объявления сущностей, некоторые подробности которых имеет смысл определять только в наследниках.

И создать вы тогда сможете экземпляр наследника, а не базового класса.

Comment: Спасибо за советы,
в общем я пытаюсь побороть в коде warning статического анализатора кода, MISRA.BASE.MANYDEFS "Both overriding and overridden virtual functions have definitions".
Чувствую без перепиливания кода не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Чисто виртуальная функция обязана быть определена в производном классе. У Вас такового нет. Либо создавайте его и определяйте, либо убирайте чистую виртуальность.